# Mule xpath fails with Message payload is of type: String

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I recently started using **Mule** with **Anypoint** studio and of course I get error very often.

Currently I am accessing a **SOAP** service with `<cxf:jaxws-client>` and `<http:outbound-endpoint>` and from the SOAP response that I get I want to perform a check on a specific body element.

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="Send-To-Selligent">

    <cxf:jaxws-client
        wsdlLocation="http://online.vikingdirekt.at/automation/individual.asmx?WSDL"
        clientClass="org.tempuri.Individual" port="IndividualSoap" operation="TriggerCampaign"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="CXF">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>

    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
        doc:name="DOM to XML" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://online.vikingdirekt.at/automation/individual.asmx"
        method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
        <response>
            <object-to-string-transformer />
        </response>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>

    <message-filter onUnaccepted="ExceptionFlow"
        doc:name="SOAP response must be successfull">
        <expression-filter
            expression="#[xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0']"
            doc:name="Expression" />
    </message-filter>

</flow>
```

From mule debuging I have extracted this info:

After the `<http:outbound-endpoint>` the payload contains a `ReleasingInputStream` which I transform to a String (the soap response xml) with the

```
<response>
    <object-to-string-transformer />
</response>
```

Unfortunately, when the flow reaches the `xpath3(...)`

I get this

```
2015-05-06 15:56:29 WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain:289 - Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}Individual#{http://tempuri.org/}TriggerCampaign has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:365)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:318)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.triggerCampaign(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithProxy(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:185)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:127)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:189)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:182)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:181)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:39)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:160)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.processNext(MuleUniversalConduit.java:345)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:248)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:190)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed.
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:202)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:183)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:161)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:229)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluateBoolean(DefaultExpressionManager.java:356)
    at org.mule.routing.filters.ExpressionFilter.accept(ExpressionFilter.java:123)
    at org.mule.routing.MessageFilter.accept(MessageFilter.java:85)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:38)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: [Error: null pointer or function not found: xpath3]
[Near : {... xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Bo ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1028)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:993)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:343)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:140)
    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.optimize(ASTNode.java:159)
    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:115)
    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.BinaryOperation.getReducedValueAccelerated(BinaryOperation.java:112)
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:113)
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:943)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:72)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:198)
    ... 73 more
2015-05-06 15:56:31 ERROR CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:337 - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. [Error: null pointer or function not found: xpath3]
[Near : {... xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Bo ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1] (org.mule.mvel2.PropertyAccessException)
  org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer:1028 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/mvel2/PropertyAccessException.html)
2. Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:202 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
3. Execution of the expression "xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: null pointer or function not found: xpath3]
[Near : {... xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Bo ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1028)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:993)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:343)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

According to [Mule documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XPath) String input should be fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which Mule version are you using ?

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary Mule 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the error is:

```
Error: null pointer or function not found: xpath3
```

So it's not related to the payload being a string at all but instead to the fact that Mule doesn't recognize `xpath3` as a valid function.

XPath 3 has been added to Mule 3.6.0 so make sure you run your application on this version of the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by David  the root cause will be with the xpath3 notation.

after changing the xpath3 to xpath and make sure that you have to name space manager in your flow with prefix as "soap" and targeturi accordingly.

Comment: I tried what you said. I put
 
`<mulexml:namespace-manager>
  <mulexml:namespace prefix="soap"
   uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
 </mulexml:namespace-manager>` 

before my flow and changed to
 
`expression="#[xpath3('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/TriggerCampaignResponse/TriggerCampaignResult').text == '0']"
            doc:name="Expression" />` 

but now getting
 
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:363)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the application in debug and check the xpath expression.

And also observed that you are still using the xpath3 in expression.